# Cannot see Jmeter measurement filter in influxdb

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb-2

I was trying to interate Jmeter, influxDB and Grafana to see the test results.

I am running docker containers with below versions

```
INFLUXDB_VERSION=2.1.1
Grafana v8.5.0
Jmeter 5.4.1
```

After I create the data source in Grafana I can see one jmeter bucket which I created in InfluxDB. However the `measurement` i setup in Jmeter Backend Listener cannot see in the inFluxDB

[image: Jmeter]

[image: influxdb]

I believe due to this reason I can't see any query result Grafana explore as below

[image: Grafana]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is due to missing `jmeter-plugin-influxdb2-listener-<>.jar` plugin. Becuse influxdb version 2.0 or above needs this Jmeter plugin.

https://github.com/mderevyankoaqa/jmeter-influxdb2-listener-plugin.

Backend Listener : `org.md.jmeter.influxdb2.visualizer.JMeterInfluxDBBackendListenerClient.`

Here is the Grafana dashboard that can be used : https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13644

Answer (score 1):

If you're running docker container**s** then I strongly doubt your InfluxDB URL of `http://localhost:8086` is correct, you will have to use the container with InfluxDB IP address both in JMeter and in Grafana.

The IP address of the InfluxDB instance can be obtained using [`docker inspect` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#get-an-instances-ip-address)

Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, you may also want to [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the Backend Listener implemenations by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend" level="error" />
```

this way you will get more information regarding what's going on under the hood.

You may also find [JMeter Integration with InfluxDB 2.0](https://qainsights.com/jmeter-integration-with-influxdb-2-0/) guide useful.

Also be aware of [JMeter InfluxDB v2.0 listener plugin](https://github.com/mderevyankoaqa/jmeter-influxdb2-listener-plugin) where you can see useful queries snippets.

Comment: I hope you meant `http://localhost:8086 is incorrect`, BTW I tried container IP in Jmeter as well instead of localhost. Hwever in that case what I found was, in the grafana `Explore` window, flux query it wont show the bucket pre populated. I already using influxDB container IP in grafana.